# Why read function works only the first time we open the object in python?

Tags: python, file

Why do we have to re-open the file object every time to read it again?

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct 24 2017, 14:48:20)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('/home/xprodigy/Prog/Practice Projects/madLibs/')
>>> file = open('madlib1')
>>> file.read()
'The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events.\n'
>>> file.read()
''
>>> file.read()
''
>>> file.close()
>>> file = open('madlib1')
>>> file.read()
'The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events.\n'
>>> file.read()
''
```

Is it supposed to happen?

How does it work internally?

Comment: Reading the file advances *its* position to the end - you can see this by printing `file.tell()`. If you want to read it again `file.seek(0)` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of reading a file as reading a book.

When you read through the book, you need to return to the first page to read it again. You can do this either by closing the book and opening it again to it's first page (ie closing and opening the file) or by flicking back to the first page without closing it (`file.seek(0)`).

Python behaves the same way.

The reason it does this is because it could be grossly inappropriate to store the entire file in memory. You don't remember every word of Lord of the Rings, do you? So it keeps in memory only the part it's reading, and the parts you explicitly write to variables.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some
>   quantity of data and returns it as a string (in text mode) or bytes
>   object (in binary mode). size is an optional numeric argument. When
>   size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be
>   read and returned; it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as
>   your machine’s memory. Otherwise, at most size bytes are read and
>   returned. If the end of the file has been reached, f.read() will
>   return an empty string ('').

So to answer your question:

Yes it is intentional.

Because f.read returns the next x amount of the file, with the default size being the entire thing, therefore to reset f.read() you will need to close and reopen the file.

In practice if you need to call f.read() on the same file twice in the same program, just save the results from the first call in a variable for the second time you need it.